# Wrong hover area with @font-face?

Tags: html, css, hover, font-face

I've got a problem with my phone book web app. Visit this demo and you'll understand:

http://what-the-fun.com/lab/

The hover area extends over the top of each button, meaning you can't easily click a button that's positioned above another button. Turn off the font-family ("EntypoRegular") on the "icon"-class to see what's causing the problem in my opinion.

How can I solve this problem? Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: By the way, you may want to add a fallback background in case a browser doesn't support -linear-gradient. Or isn't gecko based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `overflow:hidden` to `.icon` should fix it.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this working for several days. Thank you, this is amazing!